# Does anyone know why my Dragonite cannot be used in battles or online?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

So I have this really old Dragonite from Soul Silver and I can't use her in any online battles or against my friends or anything.

She's has like 2 pages of ribbons and really good stats (I think) and I can't use her which is really annoying.

I haven't used any hacks or action replay or anything like that ever

It's Bold Natured with:

Stats:

- 330 Attack
- 265 Defense
- 267 Sp. Atk
- 254 Sp. Def
- 211 Speed

Moves:

- Fire Punch,
- Sky drop,
- Thunder Punch,
- Outrage

Anyone know why I can't use my Dragonite??

Comment: What's its nickname?

Comment: You're also missing HP with the stats...

Answer (score 2):

In ORAS, the only pokémon you are allowed to use on battle spot must have the blue pentagon symbol that indicates they originated from either XY or ORAS. The only way you can use it in a battle is if you manually challenge a specific player to a battle with the ruleset "No restrictions".

XY's battle spot does not have this restriction, so if you own XY you can use your dragonite on there.

If you want to use a dragonite on battle spot in ORAS you will unfortunately have to obtain a new one.

Source: http://www.pokemonrubysapphire.com/en-us/cool-features/the-pokemon-global-link/pgl-rating-battles

Comment: No, I can't use it XY either and my Lugia and Salamence from XD work just fine on online battles, even though it has no blue pentagon...

Comment: @Coakie - Could you double-check your dragonite's stats that you listed? At the moment, even if I assume that your dragonite has perfect IVs, your stats are impossible to obtain legitimately. Also what's its level and HP?

Comment: @Pyritie The stats seem [possible](http://prntscr.com/740dr5), if a bit bad, to me.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If you add up those EVs, you get 534, which is more than the maximum 512. Also the OP's is Bold natured.

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot to check that XD Well, if total EVs are above 510, then that's definitely why it won't be allowed online. I've used Banked stuff online all the time no problem.